# Validation errors with form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am doing an assignment for school and it is a restaurant website.  I am working on the "order online" page.  I must include a table in my website so I put it in my form with all of my menu items and their cost and the total.  The problem I am having is:  I have each menu item wrapped in a form element in order to make my Javascript work but when I try to validate it, I get errors because my fieldset is outside of a form element and if I move it around I go from 3 errors to 150 and I just don't really understand why. Also, this is causing a problem with my reset button because the reset button is in a different form element then each menu item, and finally I can't get my grand total at the bottom working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lefebvre-Oliver Final Assignment</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Final2.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function multiply(element) {
    var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.querySelectorAll('input[name=TOTAL]')[0].value = element.value * row.querySelectorAll('input[name=PRICE]')[0].value;
}
</script>

<form id="contact-form" action="script.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="file:///D:/Final%20Project/index.html"/>
<h1>Order Online</h1>

<fieldset>
<legend>Basic Information</legend>    
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""/>
     </li>
     <li>
        <label for="pwd">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value=""/>
     </li>
     </ul>
<div>Would you like the same order as last time?</div>       
       <label for="yes">Yes</label>
       <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" value="yes" checked="checked">
       <label for="no">No</label>
       <input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" value="no"/>

<div>Special Instructions:</div>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>


</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Order</legend>
<table id="OrderTable" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <th>Food Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price in ($)</th>
    <th>Total Price in ($)</th> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <th>Appetizers</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="8" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Spiedini di Albicocca al Prosciutto Crudo</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="9" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Tortino di Gorgonzola</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="8" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <th>Soup and Salads</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Zuppa di Giorno</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="5" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Minestrone Piemontese</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="5" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Zuppa de Pesce</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="8" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Insalata Mista</td>
     <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="6" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Insalata Fagioli</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="6" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Pizza</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Margherita</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="10" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Sicilian</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="12" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Chicken Florentine</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="12" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Pasta</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Bucatini all'Amatriciana</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="16" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Rigatoni Alla Siciliana</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="12" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Paglia e Fieno</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="14" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Orecchiette con Rapini</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="14" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Pappardelle con Sugo di Coniglio</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="15" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Dessert</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Chocolate Zabaglione Cake</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="6" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Zuccotto</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="6" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tira Misu</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="6" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Beverages</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Sparkling Water</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="2" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Coke, Iced Tea, Root Beer, Cream Soda</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="2" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Coffee and Brewed Decaf</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="3" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Cappuccino or Americano</td>
    <td><input name="QTY"/></td>
    <td><input name="PRICE" value="3" readonly/></td>
    <td><input name="TOTAL" readonly/></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Total Cost:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><label>Total amount</label>
    <input disabled></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your markup is wildly invalid. You can't put `<form>` elements around table rows. You really need just one form anyway.

Comment: Okay but because my Javascript is calling to the form element, when I used only 1 form element my total values in my menu did not work.  Do you have any suggestions to have only 1 form element and still make my totals work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single form element around everything and you can still access the correct inputs, relative to the row.

For example, your function could look like:

```
function multiply(element) {
    var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.querySelectorAll('input[name=TOTAL]')[0].value = element.value * row.querySelectorAll('input[name=PRICE]')[0].value;
}
```

First it gets the row that contains the three inputs, then from there it finds the `TOTAL` and `PRICE` inputs by name using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Note: `querySelectorAll` isn't supported by IE7 or lower but I doubt that will matter for an assignment.

Comment: So, I have put this in my page, it doesn't seem to be working... I will update my code in the original question and maybe you'd be able to help me from there??

Comment: What happened to the onkeyup event? Due to that being removed, the multiply function is never called. Put that back as it was and it will work.

Comment: Okay, will this still work if I have changed it to a list form instead of a table?

Comment: <fieldset>
<legend>Order</legend>
<div id="columns">
    <div class="left column">
  <ul>
    <li>Appetizers</li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
    <li>Bruschetta con Crema di Agliotoa</li>
    <li>Quantity:<input type="text" name="QTY" id="QTY" value="" onKeyUp="multiply(this)"></li>
    <li>Price:<input name="PRICE" ID="PRICE" value="8" readonly></li>
    <li>Total:<input name="TOTAL" ID="TOTAL" readonly></li>
   </ul>

Comment: Okay @MrCode I have got this all figured out and it works great! thank you so much for all of your help!